# Why isn't my TypeConverter being called / used. Program doesn't appear to recognise it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've got a TypeConverter class linked to my database, but it doesn't seem to be getting called and therefore i'm getting the following error

```
ForecastAQSpecified.java:9: error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.

private final java.time.LocalDate dt = null;
```

dt is the datetime I get in my JSON response in the form of an epoch Int. I'm looking to convert this to a LocalDate. My Entity class is as follows

```
    @Entity(tableName = "future_AQ", indices = [Index(value = ["dt"], unique = true)])
    data class ForecastAQ(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val id: Int? = null,
        @Embedded
        val components: Components,
        val dt: Int,
        @Embedded
        val main: Main
    )
```

val dt: Int is the what I am looking to convert. My TypeConverter class is as follows

```
object DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun stringToDate(str: String?) = str?.let {
        LocalDate.parse(it, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun dateToString(localDate: LocalDate?) = localDate?.format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
    )

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun timestampToDateTime(dt : Int?): LocalDate? {
        try {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
            val netDate = dt?.times(1000L)?.let { Date(it) }
            val sdf2 = sdf.format(netDate)

            return LocalDate.parse(sdf2, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

            Log.d("TAG", "date " + LocalDate.parse(sdf2, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).toString());
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            return null
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

The first two are required in another part of the database where I receive the date response as a String. They are getting called just fine. My The final one is not however - and this is the one I need to convert the Int to a DateTime object

The database class is as follows for reference

```
@Database(
    entities = [CurrentConditions::class, ConditionsLocation::class, ForecastWeather::class, ForecastAQ::class],
    version = 1
)

@TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
abstract class ConditionsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getCurrentConditionsDAO() : CurrentConditionsDAO
    abstract fun getConditionsLocationDAO() : ConditionsLocationDAO
    abstract fun getForecastWeatherDAO() : ForecastWeatherDAO
    abstract fun getForecastAirQualDAO() : ForecastAqDAO

    companion object{
        @Volatile private var instance: ConditionsDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also {
                instance = it
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
            ConditionsDatabase::class.java, CURRENT_CONDITIONS_DATABASE_NAME)
                .build()
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class instead of object

replace

```
object DateConverter {
```

to

```
class DateConverter {
```

remove JvmStatic annotation